# With fixed $b$, the function $f(a, b)$ is a polynomial in $a$ of degree $b$. What can be said about the growth of this function?

Tags: analysis, functions

I've encountered a strange function $f(a, b)$ which is a polynomial in $a$ of degree $b$. I'm curious about any properties that such a function might have (Is this widely studied? Does it have a name?), but particularly about its growth as $a,  b \to \infty$. For instance, may we find a constant $C$ such that

$$f(a, b) < Ce^{a + b}$$

for all large enough $a, b$? I think this is intuitively true, but I'm not sure of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can come up with a sensible bound, because $$f(a,b)=g(b)a^b$$is such a function no matter what function $g$ is (as long as it's never zero). And no matter what bound we try to come up with, we can make $g$ grow fast enough that we go beyond that bound.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. To have such a function, we can pick, for each natural number $b$, an arbitrary polynomial $p_b(X)$ of degree $b$ and define $f(a,b)=p_b(a)$. For example, me might end up with $$f(a,b)=u_ba^b+v_b$$
where $u_b,v_b$ are arbitrary and thus can destroy any desired growth bound.